# Display content that was initially hidden onload

Tags: javascript, onload, display

`resultTable` is initially hidden. When play button is clicked, the game will run and it will display the finalscore inside the hidden content. I need a function to display the finalscore.  Currently the `showResult` function I have is not working (obviously)

I deleted unnecessary contents because the whole thing is a little big and messy. Hope the code still makes sense.

```
<body onload="loadGame()">
    <div>
        <button onclick="playButton()" id="play">Play</button>
    </div>
    <div id="resultTable" >
        <span id="result"></p>
    </div>

    <script>
        function loadGame(){
            var hideResult = document.getElementById("resultTable");
            hideResult.style.display = "none";
        }
        function playButton(){
            playGame();
            showResult();
        }
        function playGame(){
            /*Some code here*/
            document.getElementbyId("result").innerHTML = "finalscore";
        }
        function showResult(){
            var show = document.getElementById("resultTable"); //fixed.
            show.style.display = "block";
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: `getElementsByClassName()` will return a group/collection of elements. If you only have one element you want to display then I suggest you target the `ID` or give that element an `ID`. If you wish to display multiple elements that share this `class` name then you need to loop through the collection. A for loop would be simple enough **OR** simply use `document.getElementsByClassName("resultTable")[0];` assuming you want the target the first return/result from the collection.

Comment: You've used `getElementsByClassName()` when you meant `getElementById()` (which is what you *correctly* used to hide that element in the first place).

Comment: Sorry, thats actually a typo.  its actually getelementsbyId.  The result is the same.  Nothing will come out upon button clicked.

Comment: If it's a typo then please [edit] your question to fix it, otherwise that's what all the answers will be about. *"its actually getelementsbyId"* - That would be a typo too, because there should be no "s" after "element" in the function name, nor should it be all in lower-case. **These details are important and we can't help you unless you describe them accurately.**

Comment: @Frank have you checked your browser console for error reports? Or used it doe debugging? `console.log(show);` should log the html elements you are trying to display, if it doesn't log then you have something else wrong with your selector.

Comment: The issue was the typo afterall....  Thanks to all.   stared at these code for over hour and coulnd't figure out what went wrong.

Comment: First. you need to look what the console says. It is the first place where you should look. Second, I didn't see anything wrong in your code except the typo. You code is [like this](https://jsfiddle.net/guzgarcia/snjuxuu0/) and it works as expected.

Comment: @Frank next time check your browser console. It will help you a lot while debugging.

Answer (score 0):

Change the way you are finding the element to set its display as block or none. You are using the "getElementsByClassName" method, but there is no element with such classname in the DOM.

Moreover, the "getElementsByClassName" will return you an array of all the elements, if found, in the DOM and you have to loop through the array to access it.

```
 function showResult(){
            document.getElementById("resultTable").style.display = "block";
        }
```